# docker env issue with .htacess (lamp)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-mac

I have finished setting up an image for LAMP, everything seems to work fine but for some reason, my routes are not working due to an issue with my .htacess

I keep getting a 500 Internal Server Error

but when I delete all the content from my .htaccess it does shows my homepage.

my Apache folder:

Dockerfile

```
RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade;

# enabling mod_rewrite
RUN cp /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/

# Copy apache vhost file to proxy php requests to php-fpm container
COPY apache.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/demo.apache.conf
RUN echo "Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/demo.apache.conf" \
    >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

apache.conf

```
ServerName localhost

LoadModule deflate_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Proxy .php requests to port 9000 of the php-fpm container
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/var/www/html/$1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    # Send apache logs to stdout and stderr
    CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common
    ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
</VirtualHost>
```

My PHP folder:

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2.7-fpm-alpine3.7
RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade;

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

public_html/.htaccess

```
## Manejo de errores de Apache. Cuando se produzca uno de estos errores, redirigimos a una pagina especial desarrollada por nosotros.
ErrorDocument 401 /error401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html
  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 
Options +FollowSymLinks
# Evitar escaneos y cualquier intento de manipulaci�n malintencionada
# de la URL. Con esta regla es imposible lanzar ataques de inyecci�n (SQL, XSS, etc)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(-|\.|') [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.*)(<|>|%3C|%3E)(.*) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(java|curl|wget)(.*) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.*)(libwww-perl|libwwwperl|snoopy|curl|wget|winhttp|python|nikto|scan|clshttp|archiver|loader|email|harvest|fetch|extract|grab|miner|suck|reaper|leach)(.*) [NC,OR]
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/,|/;|/<|/>|/'|/`|/%2C|/%3C|/%3E|/%27|/////) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)(%00|%08|%09|%0A|%0B|%0C|%0D|%0E|%0F|%2C|<|>|'|%3C|%3E|%26%23|%27|%60)(.*) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(%00|%08|%09|%0A|%0B|%0C|%0D|%0E|%0F|%2C|%3C|%3E|%27|%26%23|%60)(.*) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)('|-|<|>|,|/|\\|\.a|\.c|\.t|\.d|\.p|\.i|\.e|\.j)(.*) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^(.*)(<|>|'|%3C|%3E|%27)(.*) [NC]
 
## Evitar que se liste el contenido de los directorios
Options All -Indexes
## Lo mismo que lo anterior
IndexIgnore *
# Protegerse contra los ataques DOS limitando el tama�o de subida de archivos
LimitRequestBody 10240000

#-#-#-#- PHPost .htaccess -#-#-#-#
# INDEX
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?do=home [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^pagina([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ index.php?do=home [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^cuenta.php$ inc/php/cuenta.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^agregar.php$ inc/php/agregar.php [QSA,L]
#PERFIL
RewriteRule ^perfil/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ inc/php/perfil.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^perfil/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$ inc/php/perfil.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^perfil/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ inc/php/perfil.php?user=$1&pid=$2 [QSA,L]
# POSTS
#RewriteRule ^posts$ index.php?do=posts [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^posts/$ index.php?do=posts [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^mi/$ index.php?do=portal [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^posts/([a-z]+)$ index.php?do=posts&action=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^posts/pagina([0-9]+)$ index.php?do=posts&page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^posts/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?do=posts&cat=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^posts/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/pagina([0-9]+)$ index.php?do=posts&cat=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^posts/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ index.php?do=posts&cat=$1&post_id=$2&title=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^posts/editar/([0-9]+)$ inc/php/agregar.php?action=editar&pid=$1 [QSA,L]
# RECUPERAR PASS Y VALIDAR CUENTA
RewriteRule ^password/(.+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)/?$ inc/php/password.php?hash=$1&type=$2&email=$3
RewriteRule ^validar/(.+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)/?$ inc/php/password.php?hash=$1&type=$2&email=$3
# FOTOS
RewriteRule ^fotos/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).php$ inc/php/fotos.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fotos/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ inc/php/fotos.php?action=album&user=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fotos/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ inc/php/fotos.php?action=album&user=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fotos/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).html$ inc/php/fotos.php?action=ver&user=$1&fid=$2 [QSA,L]
# ADMIN
RewriteRule ^admin/afs/editar/([0-9]+)$ inc/php/admin.php?action=afs&act=editar&aid=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/medals/editar/([0-9]+)$ inc/php/admin.php?action=medals&act=editar&mid=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/medals/nueva inc/php/admin.php?action=medals&act=nueva [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/news/editar/([0-9]+)$ inc/php/admin.php?action=news&act=editar&nid=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/news/nueva inc/php/admin.php?action=news&act=nuevo [QSA,L]
# MODERACI�N
RewriteRule ^moderacion/buscador/([0-2]+)/([0-2]+)/([A-Za-z0-90.9.:a_zA_z_+_%20_�?�!@,'-]+)$ inc/php/moderacion.php?action=buscador&act=search&m=$1&t=$2&texto=$3 [QSA,L]

#HISTORIAL DE MODERACI�N
RewriteRule ^mod-history/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/ inc/php/mod-history.php?ver=$1 [QSA,L]

#EXTRAS
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).php$ inc/php/ajax_files.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$ inc/php/$1.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ inc/php/$1.php?action=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$ inc/php/$1.php?action=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ inc/php/$1.php?action=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]

#NO PERMITIR LA DESCARGA DE ARCHIVOS .TPL
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|ini|log|cfg|tpl)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: What debugging have you tried?  Have you checked the Apache or PHP logs?  Have you tried adding your RewriteRules one small section at a time to try to identify if there is a problem section? Just looking at your RewriteRules they look a bit strange - it looks like each `RewriteCond` section is missing the corresponding `RewriteRule`.  Eg the very first 2 conditions, which say "*if the request is for a file or a directory which does not exist ...*", are very standard and are usually followed by a RewriteRule which sends the request to your front end controller, eg `index.php`.

Comment: Some references to check: [Laravel's .htaccess](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation#pretty-urls), or [Codeigniter's](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file), a [reference question and answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever), and [the Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html).